# Loading image files in Resources to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone

I'm building an app that randomly chooses and displays two images from bunch of images from Resources folder.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    srandom(time(0));

    NSMutableArray *paths = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:nil] mutableCopy];

    for(NSString *filename in paths)
    {
        filename=[filename lastPathComponent];
        [filenames addObject:filename];
    }

    [paths release];
    [self reset];
}
```

Checking for [paths count] returns successfully the number of images, but nothing is being allocated to filenames array..
filenames is an NSMutableArray and it is allocated in initWithNibName.
What could be wrong?
In addition, [paths count] is returning higher number than the actual number of images in Resources... which is kinda freaky..
I've spent so many hours trying to figure this out, but got stuck...
Could anyone please help me???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your initWithNibName method?
Also, I'm a little suspicious of your use of "filename".
Try omitting that variable inside your for loop, like this:

```
for (NSString *filename in paths)
{
 NSLog("@ filename is %@", filename);
 [filenames addObject: [filename lastPathComponent]];
 NSLog(@" filenames array length is now %d", [filenames count]);
 }
```

What exactly is coming out of each filename in paths?

Comment: putting your code says that filename is allocated right, but filename array length is constantly zero. what could be wrong?

Comment: Where and how are you declaring the filenames array (in the .h file?)
Put this line above the for loop:
    NSLog(@" filenames is 0x%x", filenames);
That should tell you if it's actually allocated or not.

Comment: trying that NSLog tells me that filenames is 0x0, which I assume its not being allocated... filenames is declared in .h file as follows: NSMutableArray *filenames;  and allocated in initWithNibName... should I declare its property as well?

Comment: That makes me wonder if your initWithNibName is being called.  Trying putting that same NSLog in there, right after the filenames allocation.

Comment: ur right! NSLog in initWithName doesn't appear on console, so apparently it's not being called... but I thought it was the first function to be called by default? How should I explicitly call it?

Comment: I don't use IB very much so I can't tell you off-hand how to invoke it from there.  But here's something that will work: write another init method like this:
   - (id) init { if ( self=[super init] ) { filenames=... ; currentPlayers = ...;} return self;}